Reassigning stderr handle to parent handle doesn't seem to work
I have a simple program that uses FreeConsole() and AllocConsole() to run in a separate console window.  I want to redirect the new console's stderr to the parent console, but this code still prints stderr messages to the new console window.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  HWND parent_console = GetConsoleWindow();
  HANDLE parent_stderr_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

  FreeConsole();
  if (!AllocConsole()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating new console.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (!SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, parent_stderr_handle)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting stderr handle.\n"); // should appear on parent console
    return 1;
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "Error message should appear on parent console.\n");
  getchar();

  return 0;
}


Does opening the file CONOUT$ with CreateFile  work better than GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE)?

Right, this is working per design but is not what you want.  FreeConsole() divorces this process (all your code at runtime) from the console window it was launched in.  Hence the process can't print to it anymore even with the efforts of getting the parent_stderr_handle assigned prior to the divorce.
I think you could re-attach the process to the console -- using AttachConsole() maybe? But this I think would be useless even if you could, because I believe ALL output will go to the parent window -- not just the stderr that you hoped.
